# Bitnami Eclipse PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, bitnami

I installed Bitnami WAMP Stack in Windows 7 and I am trying to get my eclipse php code to run. I found a link online that said to add an alias, but that didn't work, how do I get the code to run in

```
http://localhost/greenmugcafe/
```

if my eclipse workspace is located here

```
C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\greenmugcafe ?
```

Edit: I could not find anything on doing this for Bitnami WAMP but I found a few for the Bitnami Django stack.

Any Help at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would run from `http://localhost/greenmugcafe/` if you changed the virtual host directory of localhost to `C:/Users/Robert/Documents/GitHub/`

Personally, I think it would be better to create a local domain called greenmugcafe.dev rather than having a folder greenmugcafe in the localhost domain.

**How to setup virtual hosts in WAMP**

Make sure virtual hosts have been enabled:

1. Edit `/installdir/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`
2. Search for line that includes `httpd-vhosts.conf` and uncomment it by removing the # at the start

Adding a new virtual host:

1. Edit the `hosts` file on your windows system (usually located at `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\`)
2. Add the following to the end of the hosts file `127.0.0.1 greenmugcafe.dev`. This tells your computer that any url with a value of `greenmugcafe.dev` should be routed to `127.0.0.1` (aka localhost).
3. Save the `hosts` file and now edit this file `/installdir/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
4. Add the greenmugcafe.dev virtual host entry at the bototm of the  `/installdir/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file, save, and restart the server.

Here's the code:

```
#greenmugcafe
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@greenmugcafe.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Robert/Documents/GitHub/greenmugcafe/"
  ServerName greenmugcafe.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/greenmugcafe.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/greenmugcafe.dev-access.log" common
  <Directory "C:/Users/Robert/Documents/GitHub/greenmugcafe/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now http://greenmugcafe.dev will point to C:/Users/Robert/Documents/GitHub/greenmugcafe/

This method will also work for other WAMP stacks like Wamp Server and XAMPP.

For a launched website on a linux server, instead of the windows host file, we would change the `a record` of the domain name to point to the server IP address. Then we still need to setup the virtual host so the server knows to recognise the domain name and point it to the correct folder on the server.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Hello. I made the "REPLACE WITH BITNAMI LOCALHOST FOLDER" by "C:/BitNami/wampstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/htdocs" (assuming backslashes-forwardslashes don't matter as long as I'm consistent) and now I cannot restart the server. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Slashes do matter, they will need to be forward (/) slashes.
I gave you the wrong file to add the virtualhost code, that's probably why bitnami isn't restarting.

Add the code to this file: /installdir/apache2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf instead.

Comment: The only file I can find in httpd.conf containing the text you mentioned is `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` but that is located in the `extra` folder and your saying its located in the root of `conf`? Which should I try?

Comment: That's the one, try conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it didn't work. I scrolled to the bottom of httpd.conf and saw `Include "C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/conf/ssi.conf"` which as a mix of backslash and forwardslash. Do I need to do something like this? Also this `AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\BitNami\\WAMPST~1.16-\\apache2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/BitNami/wampstack-5.4.16-0/apache2 -f C:\\BitNami\\WAMPST~1.16-\\apache2\\conf\\httpd.conf'` apears in the error.log, maybe it helps?

Comment: I'm going to uninstall and reinstall a fresh copy of BitNami. I'll get back to you if it still doesn't work!

Comment: Can you post your conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file in the question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36211/discussion-between-robert-and-hiphiparray)